# Цифра, на которую оканчивается число

Tags: java

Описание.

> Дано два целых положительных числа: a_ и _b. Требуется написать программу, которая находит цифру, на которую оканчивается число a^b.
>
> Формат входных данных. В первой строке входного файла записаны два числа a и b, разделенные пробелом, где (1 <= a, b <= 10000).
>
> Формат выходных данных. В выходной файл следует записать одну цифру - ту, на которую оканчивается число a^b.
>
> `Примеры:
> Input   Output
> 2 2
> 4`

Comment: это ты сегодня тут задания раздаешь субботние?

Comment: в чем собственно проблема?

Comment: Я всё жду когда кто-нибудь поднимет вопрос об абсолютной неуместности подобных постов... И, кстати, кормление подобных посетителей приводит к увеличению их количества.

Comment: Ужас не от таких вопросов, а от того, что зайдет следующий такой же посетитель и задаст тот же вопрос, но на c++, c#, delfi, php. Ведь здесь на java, а значит ему не подходит :)  
А вообще Вы правы. Наверно тоже перестану отвечать на такие вопросы :)

Comment: Сдается мне, это [задача из этого архива](http://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=79).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Принцип работы основан на том, что последняя цифра будет повторятся с определенной периодичностью, например если число оканчивается на 2, то любая его степень будет давать последнюю цифру `2, 4, 8, 6, 2, 4, 8...`
Приведенный алгоритм работает с минимально необходимыми числами, для решения задачи, поэтому превышения `MAX_INTEGER`  не вызовет.

```
static int lastNumber(int base, int stepen){
    if (stepen==0) return 1;
    int last=base%10;
    int[] mods={1,1,4,4,2,1,1,4,4,2};
    int step=stepen%mods[last];
    if (step==0) step=mods[last];
    return ((int) Math.pow(last, step))%10;
}
```

Небольшой тест. Степени больше 17 не беру, чтобы не вызвать превышение MAX_DOUBLE

```
int count=0;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<17; j++){
        if (lastNumber(i, j)!=(Math.pow(i, j)%10)) count+=1;
    }
}
System.out.println(count); // 0
```

Comment: Я забивал остатки и делал switch по последней цифре A
    int d2[] = {2, 4, 8, 6};  
    int d3[] = {3, 9, 7, 1};  
    int d4[] = {4, 6};  
    int d7[] = {7, 9, 3, 1};  
    int d8[] = {8, 4, 2, 6};  
    int d9[] = {9, 1};  
    ...  
    switch (a % 10)  
    {  
      case 0: case 1: case 5: case 6: k = a % 10; break;  
      case 2: k = d2[(b - 1) % 4]; break;  
      case 3: k = d3[(b - 1) % 4]; break;  
      case 4: k = d4[(b - 1) % 2]; break;  
      case 7: k = d7[(b - 1) % 4]; break;  
      case 8: k = d8[(b - 1) % 4]; break;  
      case 9: k = d9[(b - 1) % 2]; break;  
    }